# how do i uninstall ncbi blast while the uninstall program failed

Tags: blast, ncbi

I've download the ncbi blast, but the version is too old ,so i want to uninstall it and reinstall a new one ,but the uninstall program the dmg contain failed me, I think maybe because the mac m1 chip do not support, so how do i uninstall it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjw6v.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix4Qg.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8jIM.png

Comment: can you see the picture

Comment: i remember i put several screenshot behind it

Comment: i am stucking on this